# If in cursor.fetchall there is a certain element, then print

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite

Through a `cursor.fetchall()[0]` i get a row from the database in which it is sought if the last trend on the stock exchange (already entered in the database) is positive or negative. Through `OR` one is taken only one: or only `negative` or only `positive`, depending on what is the last one (so the first in temporal order). Positive or negative only selected via a combobox. So far everything is ok.

```
cursor.execute("SELECT american_company, asian_company FROM financial_values WHERE positive =? OR negative=? LIMIT 1", [combo_value_positive, combo_value_negative])
Last_value = cursor.fetchall()[0]
```

With a condition (`if`), I would like to make sure that if the last value is positive, then something is printed. On the contrary if the last value is negative, then another is printed. So I would like to seek the name of a company based on positive or negative within Last `Value = Cursor.fetchall()[0]`. Positive or negative are searched precisely by Last_Value.

```
if Last_value == positive: #HERE, i want to use positive that of the database of Last value 
print("value positive")

else: #negative
print("value negative")
```

I wrote `==` but obviously it's not good. I get the error, because there is no item defined with this name, but I would like to use the database directly of `Last_value = cursor.fetchall()[0]`

```
NameError: name 'positive' is not defined
```

How can i?

**UPDATE**

**As you can see in Last_value I used OR, so positive or negative. Only the latest (I mean the most recent) american_company and asian_company are taken, based on whether the latter is positive or negative. With if Last_value, I wanted to be able to choose "if the last american_company and asian_company were collected thanks to positive or thanks to negative (only one of negative or positive)**

Comment: `last_value` is the entire row that was fetched.  What column specifically are you looking for?

Comment: @JohnGordon Yes. The column I'm looking for is called positive (and then the other column negative)

Comment: Then add those column(s) to the SELECT statement, so they will appear in the output.  What is the difficulty?

Comment: @JohnGordon Because the choice of selection (positive or negative) changes and varies from time to time. So i wanted to have it automatically choose based on ifs, searching for "positive" (or negative) in cursor.fetchall. If there is the field inside positive, or if there isn't, the output will change

Comment: I still don't understand the question.  Your SELECT statement does not include the positive/negative columns, so those columns won't be in the output.

Comment: @JohnGordon For some reasons, american_company and asian_company have to change positions. Sometimes it must read american_company and asian_company, while other times asian_company and american_company. If I reverse their position, then I have problems with WHERE positive =? Or negative = ?. I recover the wrong data. (COMMENT, PART 1)

Comment: @JohnGordon So I created Last_value to retrieve the last record which has both positive and negative. After with the condition (if), I choose whether to get the record with positive or negative (only one of the two). In fact I created 2 other cursor.fetchall () [0], one for positive and one for negative. These last 2 I have not included them in the question because they are not important for the solution (instead of getting these 2 cursor.fetchall, instead I use print for example) (COMMENT, PART 2)

Comment: Please edit your question to include some sample rows and the result you expect. That will help us understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python can only use the data you load from the database. If you want to use the value of the positive and negative columns, you have to add them to your select query.

```
cursor.execute("""
  SELECT american_company, asian_company, positive, negative
  FROM financial_values
  WHERE positive =? OR negative=?
  LIMIT 1
""", [combo_value_positive, combo_value_negative])

# Use fetchone() to get just one row.
row = cursor.fetchone()
```

`fetchone` returns a [tuple](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_tuples.asp) of the results. Positive and negative are the 3rd and 4th items in the select list. Tuples start at 0 so `row[2]` is the value for `positive` and `row[3]` is the value for `negative`.

```
if row[2]
    print("its positive")
if row[3]
    print("it's negative")
```

Comment: I was not looking for this. Maybe i explained myself wrong. As you can see in Last_value I used OR, so positive or negative. Only the latest (i mean the most recent) american_company and asian_company are taken, based on whether the latter is positive or negative. With if Last_value, i wanted to be able to choose "if the last american_company and asian_company were picked up thanks to positive or thanks to negative (only one of negative or positive). By writing if row [2] as you suggested, i get a completely different thing. I hope you can help me

Comment: @Bobby "*Only the latest (i mean the most recent) american_company and asian_company are taken*". No, you're just getting one row that matches. If you want the most recent, you have to `order by` something. As for the rest, I'm sorry, I don't understand. Edit your question to include some sample data and a clear example of the result you want.